# How to self-reference table during initialization

Tags: lua, lua-table

Is there a shorter way to do this:

```
local thisismytable = {
    non = sequitur
}
thisismytable.whatismytable = thisismytable
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I don't want to re-create pre-existing functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

If you can stand the difference between these two expressions  `thisismytable:whatismytable()` instead of `thisismytable.whatismytable`, you could do:

```
local thisismytable = {
    non = sequitur,
    whatismytable = function (self) return self end
}
```

Testing:

```
print(thisismytable)
print(thisismytable:whatismytable())
```

More usage:

```
print(thisismytable:whatismytable().non)
```

Comment: Wow, that's actually kind of genius. Thank you.

Comment: It's a possibility, but not that genius :/ `:` just sends the accessed table as first argument to called function - it's just a wrapper around your attempt with function overhead.

Comment: @Youka I agree. I'd just do it the straightforward way like in the question.

Comment: @Youka Yeah, I decided to avoid the overhead, but still, as just kind of puzzle-solving, I thought it was pretty clever.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. I use a helper function.

```
local function ref(t)
  for k, v in next, t do
    if v == ref then t[k] = t end
  end
  return t
end

local root = ref{left=ref, right=ref}
assert(root.left == root)
```